# How can I use the output of this code and the Telegram API to alert me of a new entry?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to scrape recent releases of movies with the URL. But I want to be notified of each new release. I also want to set a timer, let's say every two hours the script will check for a new movie release. If there's a new release, it would be sent to my Telegram bot. I have no idea on how to go about that yet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request("https://www.thenetnaija.com/videos/movies", headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
b4 = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
movie_list = b4.find_all("div", {"class" : "video-files"})
for allContainers in movie_list:
    filmName = allContainers.find('img').get('alt')
print(filmName)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request("https://www.thenetnaija.com/videos/movies", headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
b4 = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
movie_list = b4.find_all("div", {"class" : "video-files"})

for allContainers in movie_list:
    filmName = allContainers.find('img').get('alt')
printed = []
print(filmName)
while True:
    if filmName not in printed:
        requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot{"insert bot_token here"}/sendMessage?chat_id={"insert chat id here"}&text={}".format(filmName))
        time.sleep(10)
        printed.append(filmName)
```

Thanks so much @Aladdin Jiroun!

Answer (score 0):

to send notification for you from telegram bot

1 - first talk to this bot: @userinfobot
get the id

2 - get your bot token from @botfather

3 - send any message to your bot

(the above steps only one time)

4- make get request

[https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={notification_text}](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Bbot_token%7D/sendMessage?chat_id=%7Bchat_id%7D&text=%7Bnotification_text%7D)

Comment: Thanks so much, after a few tries, it works!